# Webservices (wsdl) and phpunit

Tags: web-services, symfony1, wsdl, phpunit

I have some needs, for a specific test type:

I would like to check through phpunit tests, some webservices state, in a first time, and the file parsing, in a second.

I use Symfony and SFphpunit plugin, but didn't find tools in phpunit library which can help me to do it.
I'm write, or anyone has an answer?

Thanks,
Yan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, soap tests are more functional than unit.

I'm not sure if you can write functional tests with sfPHPUnitPlugin. Maybe you should check sfPHPUnit2Plugin for that:

- [sfPHPUnit2Plugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfPHPUnit2Plugin) - alternative plugin for phpunit
- [testing symfony projects with PHPUnit](http://dev.esl.eu/blog/2010/02/25/testing-symfony-projects-with-phpunit/) - functional testing with phpunit and symfony

ckWebServicePlugin offers base [test classes](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/ckWebServicePlugin/4_0_0?tab=plugin_readme) for soap functional testing (check "Using ckTestSoapClient" part). Of course it uses lime but you could see how it's done and try to implement something similar with PHPUnit.

Good luck!